# How to override windows + s shortcut function?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-paint

Somehow I've managed to turn off the instant inserting into onenote. Currently it only copies the clipped picture onto the clipboard. But I would like to insert it instantly into paint, like it worked with onenote. Is it possible? Thank you.

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  This keyboard shortcut only exists if OneNote is installed.  If you disabled it then you disable while within Onenote.  You would have to write your own service ( programming ) to do this.

Comment: My question is clear. But thank you, I didn't know that this feature comes with onenote. So if there isn't any other solutions, sending just onto the clipboard still be okay.

Comment: It might be clear to you. But you are not the one being asked to answer the question. If you want to send it to the clipboard it would require your own custom service. I suggest just use the Snipping Tool.  Of course when I used it, an option to send it to the clipboard was offered, when I checked the options I was able to set it to "To clipboard only" which is what you want.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry. Snipping tool sounds good. I see it can save directly into some picture format. How can I set some shortcut for starting this tool?

Answer (score 0):

In OneNote, select *File -> Options* from the Ribbon bar and then select *Send to OneNote* from the list on the left.

Change the *Screen clippings* combo box setting back to "Always ask where to send" to revert back to the default behaviour.

Comment: Thank you, but I can only select a location INSIDE a onenote document.

Comment: @Mitulátbáti - Which is to be expected since the feature is enabled by OneNote.